# Handle react fetch with Openweather Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm building a simple app with React (I'm learning it). I don't understand how to render the data object correcly since I can't write *day.key* to access the information I want to print.
Can you help me?

Here is the code I'm using:
Fetch request:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Day from './Day';

const DayList = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const lat = 45.68;
        const long = 9.23;
        const apikey = "apikey";

        fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&exclude=current,minutely,hourly&appid="+apikey)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setData(data.daily)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="day-list">
            { data && <Day data = { data } /> }
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default DayList;
```

Here is the render component where I don't know how to access data

```
const Day = ( {data} ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.keys(data).map((day) => (
                <div className="day">{ ??? }</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Day;
```

Example response can be found [here](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api);

[Screen of the console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrFOa.png)
Thanks

Comment: can you add sample data for the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you get from your code is array and not object, so the result should be similar to this -

```
const Day = ( {data} ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((day) => (
                <div className="day">{day.sunrise}</div>
                <div className="day">{day.sunset}</div>
                <div className="day">{day.temp.min}</div>
                <div className="day">{day.temp.max}</div>
                .....
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Day;
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! So it's an array since i'm passing data.daily, instead of the entire data right?

Comment: Yeah, the `daily` is array whereas `data` there is object

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting data.daily as the data (state variable in your component), you need to use `data.map` to access the values as `data.daily` is an array.

```
const Day = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((day) => (
                <p>Temp: {day.temp}</p>
                <p>Feels Like: {day.feels_like}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Day;
```